# Inverse multi-line grep in perl one-liner

Tags: perl, regex-negation, one-liner

I have a text file with inconsistent formatting, but the relevant sections look like:

```
     CDS             complement(99074..99808)
                     /note="important in cell to cell spread of the virus, a
                     tegument protein"
                     /codon_start=1
```

As part of an existing bash pipeline, I need to remove the pattern of /note="anything" to get

```
     CDS             complement(99074..99808)
                     /codon_start=1
```

I've tried several methods to inverse grep, but the closest only works if the match is not spanning multiple lines:

```
perl -ne '/\/\bnote\b\="[^"]+"/||print' file.txt
```

I can match the strings I wish to remove by checking with the following perl one-liner, but so far I cannot combine the two methods to invert the match and remove the strings that span multiple lines:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while ( /(\s+\/\bnote\b\="[^"]+")/sg )' file.txt
```

Doing the first one-liner as -0777 results in no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple approach involves reading the entire stream into memory. This is done by telling Perl to treat the whole file as a single line using `-0777` or the new `-g`.

```bash
perl -0777pe's{^\s*/note="[^"]*"\n}{}mg'
```

Doing it a line at a time is more complicated since it requires a flag to indicate whether we're in the string or not.

```bash
perl -ne'
   $f ||= m{^\s*/note="};
   print if !$f;
   $f &&= !m{"$};
'
```